# Display text inside pie chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have pie chart. I'm using `angular2-highcharts` library

```
title : { text : 'simple chart' },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129],
        }],
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        }
```

On hover it displays values.

[image]

But I want them to be displayed inside that piece. like this

[image]

How can I achieve this?

[example is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pCS33zbOpQMnZ7YHeVmA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `plotOptions` in highcharts

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y;
                },
                distance: -30,
                color:'white'
            }
        }
    },
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PjBeozIGEkCgzkI5I7EU?p=preview) demo